# How can one add superscript character like TM or Reg on a block title

Tags: blocks

I was wondering how to add superscript characters like trademark to Drupal block title.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot write “™” or “®” as such?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That would be invalid HTML

Comment: @Clive, the characters “™” or “®” are certainly allowed as data characters in HTML.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'll take your word for it; my assumption was that anything that has an equivalent _specific_ HTML entity defined (`&reg;`/`&trade;`) would have been done so for the obvious reason, not just for the sake of it. Could you provide a source?

Comment: @Clive This was my assumption too *searches for source* :-/

Comment: For example, the HTML 4.01 specification declares, in its somewhat sloppy style, the [document character set](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.1) as ISO 10646, which is equivalent to Unicode; the formal definition of allowed characters is in the [SGML Declaration of HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/sgmldecl.html), which is very theoretical – HTML was never actually implemented as an SGML application – but still reflects the reality in the sense that all Unicode characters, except characters in explicitly excluded ranges, are allowed in HTML.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Very interesting, many thanks for the explanation/links

Answer (score 3):

[Block Class Styles](https://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) may be useful:

> Extends the Block Class module to incorporate styles (or themes)
>   rather than css classes. Adds style-based tpl suggestions. Allows HTML
>   in your block titles.

Other options would be to create your block in code, and set the `$block->subject` to be your `<sup>` inclusive title, or to override the `block-XYZ.tpl.php` for the your particular block and add the title in there.

By default, [Drupal core runs `check_plain` on any UI created blocks](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/bf704d6ffe55d66a440a55a9d43e8846d46d2440:/modules/block/block.module#l906), so through the UI I don't think there's another option.

Answer (score 2):

Trademark ™ is just a character, it doesn't need html. There is no reason why you can't have special characters in block titles.

Superscript as in sup tags is a different story, see the other answer.

How to type symbols? http://www.wikihow.com/Type-Symbols-Using-the-ALT-Key

Comment: Any ideas why there are specific HTML entity tags for those characters if they're already valid HTML?

Comment: That's kind of a big question. You should see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_set and http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/index.html (yes, the author is the commenter on this page)